# Getting Zero bytes File using php image resize

Tags: php

```
function compressImage($source, $destination, $quality) {
    // Get image info 
    $imgInfo = getimagesize($source); 
    $mime = $imgInfo['mime']; 
     
    // Create a new image from file 
    switch($mime){ 
        case 'image/jpeg': 
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source); 
           imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);
            break; 
        case 'image/png': 
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($source); 
            imagepng($image, $destination, $quality);
            break; 
        case 'image/gif': 
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($source); 
            imagegif($image, $destination, $quality);
            break; 
        default: 
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source); 
           imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);
    } 
    return $destination; 
}


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $conn = $pdo->open();
    $uploadPath = "draft/"; 
        if(isset($_FILES['photo']['name'][0]) && $_FILES['photo']['size'][0] != 0 && $_FILES['photo']['error'][0] == 0) 
        {
         $filesCount = count($_FILES['photo']['name']);
         for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) { 
            $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['photo']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");
                  if(in_array($ext,$extensions)=== false){
           $_SESSION['error']  = 'extension not allowed, please choose a .jpg, .jpeg or .png file.';
      }
else{
            $new_filename = time().$i.'.'.$ext;
            // Compress size and upload image 
          compressImage($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"][$i], $uploadPath.$new_filename, 75);   
            $allfiles[] = $new_filename;
         }
         }
         $uploaded_img = implode(',',$allfiles);
        }
        else{
            $uploaded_img = '';
        }

        try{
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO marketplace (category_id, post_userid, userid, name, description, slug, price, photo, suburb_province, counter) VALUES (:category, :post_userid, :userid, :name, :description, :name, :price, :photo, :suburb_province, :counter)");
            $stmt->execute(['category'=>$category, 'post_userid'=>$post_userid, 'userid'=>$userid, 'name'=>$name, 'description'=>$description, 'slug'=>$slug, 'price'=>$price, 'photo'=>$uploaded_img, 'suburb_province'=>$suburb_province, 'counter'=>0]);
            $_SESSION['success'] = 'Product added successfully';

        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'Please choose a .jpg, .jpeg or .png file.';
        }

    $pdo->close();
}
```

Hi there I have a code below which worked properly without the `compressImage` function. After I tried to incorporate the compress function into my upload script I now get zero bytes file uploaded although it still correctly uploads an array of files

The only problem I need help with is that the uploaded file is just a name.extension with zero bytes.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `compressImage` function returns a value but you never use that returned value

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius if i use compressImage in place of $new_filename i get the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified only slightly and put together a full working example of what you are trying to accomplish - the `compressImage` function works and reduces the quality of suitable images perfectly well. Use the returned value from that function in subsequent operations

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        
        $field='photo';
        $quality=75;
        
        
        
        function compressImage( $source, $destination, $quality=75 ) {
            $imgInfo = getimagesize( $source ); 
            $mime = $imgInfo['mime'];
            
            switch( $mime ){
                case 'image/png': 
                    $image = imagecreatefrompng( $source ); 
                    $res = imagepng( $image, $destination, $quality );
                break; 
                case 'image/gif': 
                    $image = imagecreatefromgif( $source ); 
                    $res = imagegif( $image, $destination );
                break;
                
                case 'image/jpeg': 
                default: 
                    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg( $source ); 
                    $res = imagejpeg( $image, $destination, $quality );
                break;
            } 
            return $res ? realpath( $destination ) : false; 
        }



        if( isset( $_FILES[ $field ] ) ){
            
            $allfiles=array();
            $extension = array('jpeg','jpg','png','gif');
            $dir='draft';
            
            
            $targetpath=sprintf('%s/%s',__DIR__, $dir );
            $webpath=sprintf('../%s', $dir );
            
            if( !file_exists( $targetpath ) )mkdir( $targetpath, 0777, true );
            
            
            
            
            /* iterate through the files */
            foreach( $_FILES[ $field ]['name'] as $i => $void ) {
                $errors = array();
                if( !empty( $_FILES[ $field ]['tmp_name'][$i] ) ) {
                    $name = $_FILES[ $field ]['name'][$i];
                    $size = $_FILES[ $field ]['size'][$i];
                    $type = $_FILES[ $field ]['type'][$i];
                    $tmp  = $_FILES[ $field ]['tmp_name'][$i];
                    $error= $_FILES[ $field ]['error'][$i];
                    $ext  = pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
                    
                    if( $error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){
                        if( !in_array( strtolower( $ext ), $extension ) ){
                            $errors[ $name ]=sprintf('File type is invalid. Type:- %s', $ext );
                        }
                        
                        if( empty( $errors ) ){
                            
                            $targetfile = sprintf('%s/%s', $targetpath, $name );
                            $webfile = sprintf('%s/%s', $webpath, $name );                          
                            
                            $allfiles[ $webfile ]=compressImage( $tmp, $targetfile, $quality );
                        }
                    } else {
                        $errors[ $name ]='There was an error';
                    }
                }
            }
            
            
            
            
            
            printf( '<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( $allfiles, true ) );
            
            
            
            # process allfiles, add to db
            /*
            $sql='insert into marketplace (...) values (...)';
            $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
            $args=array(
                ...
                ':photo'    =>  implode( ',', array_keys( $allfiles ) ),
                ...
            );
            $stmt->execute( $args );
            */
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>PHP: Multiple file uploads with compression </title>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <input type='file' name='photo[]' multiple />
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok , thanks let me try and look at it

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with how you are trying to store the image. From what I have seen from your code is that you are using the original file name instead of the compressed file name, This can result in zero bytes being uploaded since the original file is not actually being uploaded. Try using this approach.

```
$compressed_image = compressImage($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"][$i], $uploadPath.$new_filename, 75);   

$allfiles[] = $compressed_image;
```

Comment: Well, i have tried and it still uploads a zero byte file to the folder